# Pass a "variable name" to defvar

Tags: common-lisp

I've been struggling with this for two days now, and I can't find the answer.

What I want is to define three variables, `a`, `b`, and `c` each with a value of 0.

Naive:
`(dolist (lbl '(a b c)) (defvar lbl 0))`

Doesn't do what I want. `a`, `b`, and `c` remain undefined, and `lbl` now has a value of 0.

I think I may understand why this can't work: `defvar` is a macro, not a function, and as such I am passing it the *form* `lbl`, not the current value of label (which is `a`, `b`, `c` in turn). **I think.**

But in the resulting macroexpansion, shouldn't lbl eventually be linked-up(?)  or evaluated(?) to the value I'm intending? Obviously not, either because it can't be done or I'm doing it wrong.

I want to understand:

1. How to make this work: `(dolist (lbl '(a b c)) (defvar lbl 0))`
2. What's going wrong under the hood. I have a feeling it has something to do with symbols or the mechanics of the quote operator.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers so far. Paraphrasing: "Macros get passed forms, which can be evaluated once, many times, or not at all." I got pretty wrapped up and failed to realize that the "variable name" is *purposely* not evaluated but used as is. So I probably need some kind of macro strategy to achieve the desired affect, as suggested in some of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar:

```
(dolist (lbl '(a b c))
  (let ((lbl 0))
    (print lbl)))
```

Why is `lbl` `0` and not some of `a`, `b`, `c`?

Because `LET` binds the symbol `lbl` and not its value.

Similar with `(DEFVAR FOO 3)`.

Imagine following code:

```
(DEFVAR FOO 3)
(LET ((FOO 3)) ...)
```

Now, if we compile this code, the Lisp compiler recognizes the `DEFVAR` declaration and now knows that `FOO` is a special global variable. Thus in the let form `FOO` will be dynamically bound.

Compare this code:

```
(dolist (v '(FOO)) (eval `(DEFVAR ,v 3)))
(LET ((FOO 3)) ...)
```

The compiler won't see the `DEFVAR` and does not know that it should be a global special variable. In the `LET` form, `FOO` will have a lexical binding.

Thus `DEFVAR` needs to be a macro which knows the symbol at compile time (!) and which expands into a form that informs the compiler that the symbol is a special global variable. The form also sets the value when executed.

Thus the best way to create multiple `DEFVAR` declarations from a list of variables is to write a macro, which expands into a `PROGN` form with multiple `DEFVAR`s. Inside the `PROGN`, the compiler will still recognize them.

```
CL-USER 21 > (pprint (macroexpand '(defvar* (a b c) 0)))

(PROGN (DEFVAR A 0) (DEFVAR B 0) (DEFVAR C 0))
```

Implemented as:

```
(defmacro defvar* (vars initial-value)
  `(progn
     ,@(loop for var in vars
             do (check-type var symbol)
             collect `(defvar ,var ,initial-value))))
```

Note that it makes sense to check that the variables are really provided as symbols.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for helping me see the repercussions of `eval`.

Comment: Er... wait. Is it certain that the compiler won't see the defvar inside the backquoted form? I don't yet understand the order that everything is done during compilation, but it's not like it's dependent on runtime information... Can you point me to a source you like to explain how compile-time works?

Comment: @brian_o: how would it do it? for the compiler it is data, not code. Remember: a compiler compiles code, it does not execute it.

Comment: (shrugs stupidly) Uh... I dunno... optimization? You're right of course, thanks for the reminder. I'm still learning, using emacs slime sblc. It's so good in many ways, but I don't think I have an appreciation for the separation between compiling, interpreting, macroexpansion, and run-time activities. I'll keep working on it.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few options:

With [`eval`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eval.htm), by building a `defvar` expression:

```
(dolist (lbl '(a b c))
  (eval `(defvar ,lbl 0))
```

With [`proclaim`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_procla.htm) and [`setf`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_setf_.htm) of [`symbol-value`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_symb_5.htm) (note: [`set`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_set.htm) is [deprecated](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/01_h.htm), since 1994 for what it's worth):

```
(dolist (lbl '(a b c))
  (proclaim `(special ,lbl))
  (setf (symbol-value lbl) 0))
```

This is actually mostly what [`defvar`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpar.htm) does (see notes in the linked page), but each Lisp implementation usually also records source file location, as they do for other defining macros.

---

Under the hood, `defvar` is a macro that makes the variable [`special`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/d_specia.htm) (i.e. with [dynamic extent](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_af.htm) bindings in the current [dynamic environment](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_aab.htm); note: there's no portable undoing for this!), and optionally initializes it if it's not yet bound.

The fact that it's a macro means it doesn't evaluate its arguments, so it can take the variable name literally, and it does so.  As such, `(defvar lbl 0)` will define the variable `lbl`, **not** the symbol stored in a `lbl` variable.

The fact that it optionally initializes the variable means that the initializing expression will not even be evaluated if the variable is [`boundp`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_boundp.htm).  So, its secondary effects won't happen if the variable is already initialized.  This might or might not be expected.

Note that this expression isn't actually evaluated at macro-expansion time, it's left for evaluation when the expansion is evaluated, which in a REPL means right after macro expansion (and possibly after compilation, depending on the Lisp implementation; read more about [evaluation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_a.htm) and [compilation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_b.htm), it's quite interesting).

Comment: I like the simplicity of ``(dolist (lbl '(a b c)) (eval `(defvar ,lbl 0)))``. It relies on `eval`, which is [not-desirable somehow?]. I don't know enough to know if it's safe/efficient to use here. Certainly I could use a very similar approach but write it as a macro, but I think it would ultimately be slightly longer to read and write, and slightly harder to understand (in this instance). Is it worth it to avoid `eval`?

Comment: I think you need to tell your specific need.  If you want to define **global** dynamic variables, either `eval` of `defvar` or `proclaim` followed by `setf` of `symbol-value` will do.  If you want to define **local** lexical variables, you simply can't do that, not in running code.  There is something to define variables for values in lists (trees, actually) which is `destructuring-bind`, e.g. `(destructuring-bind (a b c) (list 1 2 3) #| ... |# )`.

Comment: There's also `progv` to make an arbitrary amount of dynamic bindings (as opposed to **proclaiming** dynamic variables).  E.g. `(progv (list 'a 'b 'c) (list 1 2 3) #| ... |# )`.  Note that `eval` is not evil, although you should try to use something else before resorting to it (or due to lack of time in the attempt).  In a R**E**PL, the E stands for `eval`, and sometimes it's useful to evaluate `constantp` expressions in macros, so it has its uses.

Answer (score 2):

`defvar` is a special form which makes sure the symbol of it's first argument is a bound variable. If the variable is not bound the evaluated expression of the second argument becomes the bound variables value. Thus:

```
(defvar *x* 10) ; if *x* was not bound it's now 10
(defvar *x* 20) ; since *x* is defined nothing happens
```

Notice that `*x*` is not evaluated but is used unevaluated. In order to get the same functionality by using a variable that evaluates to a symbol which you want to exist as a variable in global scope you need to do something like this:

```
(defvar b 10)
(dolist (lbl '(a b c)) 
  (when (not (boundp lbl))
    (setf (symbol-value lbl) 0)))
```

Still, neither of the ones not already bound becomes special like with `defvar`, but at least you get the same behaviour:

```
(list a b c) ; => (0 10 0)
```

Perhaps you should just do:

```
(defvar *a* 0)
(defvar *b* 0)
(defvar *c* 0)
```

If you have a lot of variables you need to do this with you can do:

```
(defmacro defvars (lst value)
  (loop :for e :in lst
        :collect `(defvar ,e ,value) :into result
        :finally (return (cons 'progn result))))

(defparameter *w* 10)
(defvars (*q* *w* *e*) 1)
(list *q* *w* *e* ; ==> (1 10 1)
```

Also, it's really important to earmuff your global variables. Once special it will follow dynamic binding. eg.

```
(defun test ()
  (let ((*b* 15))
    (test2)))

(defun test2 ()
  *b*)

(test) ; ==> 15
```

Comment: Although I wish to understand at a deeper level, I appreciate the honesty when you said "Perhaps you should just do..." :-) In the production code I'm thinking about updating, the real list is quite a bit longer. So I likewise appreciate your follow-up macro.

Answer (score 0):

### Reimplementing DEFVAR

You can approximate the behavior of **defvar** with a function like this:

```
(defun %defvar (symbol value documentation)
  "Define a global special variable.

symbol---a symbol
value---nil or a function of zero arguments
documentation---nil or a documentation string

returns symbol

Proclaim SYMBOL globally as a special variable.  If VALUE is non-nil,
then if SYMBOL is not already bound, SYMBOL is assigned the value
returned by calling VALUE.  DOCUMENATION is assigned as the
documentation of type variable to for SYMBOL."
  (prog1 symbol
    ;; make it globally special
    (proclaim (list 'special symbol))
    ;; if a value is provided, and symbol isn't
    ;; already bound, set its value to the result
    ;; of calling the value-function
    (when (not (null value))
      (unless (boundp symbol)
        (setf (symbol-value symbol)
              (funcall value))))
    ;; set the documentation
    (setf (documentation symbol 'variable) documentation)))
```

Then you can do, e.g.,

```
CL-USER> (%defvar '*the-answer* (lambda () 42) "the answer")
*THE-ANSWER*
CL-USER> *the-answer*
42
CL-USER> (documentation '*the-answer* 'variable)
"the answer"
```

And with your original code, you could do something like:

```
(dolist (lbl '(a b c)) (%defvar lbl (lambda () 0)))
```

Now, how does this relate to what **defvar** actually does?  Well, you could now implement a defvar like macro by doing:

```
(defmacro define-var (symbol &optional (value nil value-p) documentation)
  `(%defvar
    ',symbol
    ,(if value-p `(lambda () ,value) 'nil)
    ,documentation))
```

This expands as we'd expect:

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(define-var *the-answer* 42 "the answer"))
(%DEFVAR '*THE-ANSWER* (LAMBDA () 42) "the answer")
```

You can actually use **macroexpand** to look at what an implementation does, too.  E.g., in SBCL:

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(defvar *the-answer* 42 "the answer"))
(PROGN
 (EVAL-WHEN (:COMPILE-TOPLEVEL) (SB-IMPL::%COMPILER-DEFVAR '*THE-ANSWER*))
 (SB-IMPL::%DEFVAR '*THE-ANSWER* (UNLESS (BOUNDP '*THE-ANSWER*) 42) 'T
                   "the answer" 'T (SB-C:SOURCE-LOCATION)))
```

This isn't too much different from what we wrote above, though it's handling the non-evaluation of the form when the variable is already bound in a slightly different way, and it's also got some handling for recording a source location.  The general idea is the same, though.

### Why things don't get "linked up"

> But in the resulting macroexpansion, shouldn't lbl eventually be
>   linked-up(?) or evaluated(?) to the value I'm intending?

The original code is:

```
(dolist (lbl '(a b c)) (defvar lbl 0))
```

We can macroexpand this to see what it becomes (in SBCL):

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand '(dolist (lbl '(a b c)) (defvar lbl 0)))
(BLOCK NIL
  (LET ((#:N-LIST1022 '(A B C)))
    (TAGBODY
     #:START1023
      (UNLESS (ENDP #:N-LIST1022)
        (LET ((LBL (TRULY-THE (MEMBER C B A) (CAR #:N-LIST1022))))
          (SETQ #:N-LIST1022 (CDR #:N-LIST1022))
          (TAGBODY (DEFVAR LBL 0)))
        (GO #:START1023))))
  NIL)
T
```

Now, we can still see **LBL** in two places, including in **(defvar LBL 0)**.  So why don't things get "matched up"?  To see that, we need to remember that the **defvar** *inside* the **let** will also be macroexpanded.  To what?  This:

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand '(DEFVAR LBL 0))
(PROGN
 (EVAL-WHEN (:COMPILE-TOPLEVEL) (SB-IMPL::%COMPILER-DEFVAR 'LBL))
 (SB-IMPL::%DEFVAR 'LBL (UNLESS (BOUNDP 'LBL) 0) 'T NIL 'NIL
                   (SB-C:SOURCE-LOCATION)))
```

But now we see that SBCL's internals are getting the symbol named "LBL";  the call **(sb-impl::%defvar 'lbl …)** is calling the function **sb-impl::%defvar** with the *symbol* **lbl**, and there's no connection between that symbol and the lexical variable that happens to be represented in the source by the same symbol.  After all, if you write:

```
CL-USER> (let ((a 89))
           (list 'a a))
(A 89)
```

You *want* to be able to get the symbol **a** and the number **89**, right?  The macroexpansion of **defvar** includes a call to a function with the *quotation* of one of the arguments to macro.